# How to run a java method on click from html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jpa

I am looking to add a sort button to my data that is displayed on my screen.
At the monet i have my repo set up as shown.

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {

Player findAllById(Long id);
List<Player> findByOrderByPlayerNameAsc();
}
```

And in my controller class i have it as such:

```
@GetMapping("/player")
public String displayPlayer(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("player", service.findAll());

    return "/player";
}
```

I want to be able to create a new method and have it as such so that when i click a button on the html of my application it calls this method and sorts the data. At the moment on loading of the screen it displays all data unfiltered, if i change it to use the "findByOrderByPlayerNameAsc" one it automatically filters upon loading. But i would like this to only happen when a button is clicked.

```
 public String displayPlayerFilteredByName(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("player", service.findByOrderByPlayerNameAsc());

    return "/player";
}
```

Is this possible using simply java and html?
Or is there an alternative using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way, avoiding JavaScript and dynamic front-end, would be to request from back-end newly generated view or .html of your players.

1. That requires to set a new mapping eg.

```
@GetMapping("/players/asc-names")
public String displayPlayersByPlayerNameAsc(Model model) {
   ...
}
```

where button would'be just a link to new endpoint.

2. Another way would be giving additional information to you're get `/player` request and extracting it via `@RequestBody` on back-end. But that already requeries some JavaScript being set up on the button.
3. If your application isn't too complex yet. I'd check front-end frameworks such as Angular, which could make it easier to expand in the future.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that approach @ 1. Would mean i would make a new html screen for each column that i want sortable. Seems like a lot of repetitive work so i guess i will look at angular or else try and implement this using javascript. Its only a small project that i want to create to learn programing. Thanks for your input:)